# Is there a way to contact the developer of an app on the Amazon Appstore?

Tags: amazon-appstore

For Android apps on Google Play, usually (always?) there is a developer email address you can use to contact the developer of the app. But for apps published on the Amazon Appstore, I can't see any way to contact the developer of the app; is there a way?

Comment: When I look at apps on https://www.amazon.com/appstore there is a Developer-Info section which contains an e-mail of the app developer/company.

Comment: @Robert - thanks. It seems this section only appears on the web version and not when viewing the page either in a mobile browser or through the appstore app itself.